# Which alternative port can I use for RDP?

Tags: windows-xp, remote-desktop, ports

The default port for Remote Desktop is 3389.  I would like to change the port to another port in order to thwart a brute force attack that is occuring on my machine.

What port number could I use?  I would like to avoid obvious alternative such as 3390 and 3391.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any port that's not already in use on your computer; your choice.   To get a list of ports currently being used (listening), you can use `Netstat -a` at a command prompt.

[Here's a list of TCP ports](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers) used by various software and services to help you make your choice.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;306759) should help you. You can change it to any free port allegedly, just make sure it isn't used on your system :)

Comment: Thanks, I know how to change it, just wondering which ports can I use?  I don't know which ones are free.

Comment: Go 3390, it's not a well known port and you should be fine.

Comment: I think they will try 3390 because everyone suggests it as an alternative.

Comment: Pretty much anything that isn't listed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers) is probably safe.

Comment: I may add, you might like to contact your ISP about this and get a new static ip while you are at it. Also, if you don't need to RDP to that machine, banish the service or maybe try an alternative like VNC.

Comment: VNC is even worse with the limited password length...

Comment: @billc.cn true but you could still make a password that would take thousands of years to crack but then that should be done with RDP anyway.

Comment: "This" is not helping any more. The link is broken :)